# Terraform: cannot retrieve id from azurerm_network_interface

Tags: terraform

Why is this not working for me? I have seen this code working everywhere but I keep getting the following error. So frustrating...

```
Error: Error running plan: 1 error(s) occurred:

* azurerm_virtual_machine.main: 2 error(s) occurred:

* azurerm_virtual_machine.main[0]: Resource 'azurerm_network_interface.main' does not have attribute 'id' for variable 'azurerm_network_interface.main.*.id'
* azurerm_virtual_machine.main[1]: Resource 'azurerm_network_interface.main' does not have attribute 'id' for variable 'azurerm_network_interface.main.*.id'







resource "azurerm_network_interface" "main" {
  count               = "${length(var.hostname)}"
  name                = "${var.hostname[count.index]}-nic"
  location            = "${azurerm_resource_group.main.*.location}"
  resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.main.*.name}"

  ip_configuration {
    name                          = "${var.hostname[count.index]}-ipaddress"
    subnet_id                     = "${var.subnet[count.index]}"
    private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "main" {
  name                  = "${var.aplication}-${var.region[count.index]}-${var.hostname[count.index]}-vm"
  location              = "${azurerm_resource_group.main.*.location}"
  resource_group_name   = "${azurerm_resource_group.main.*.name}"
  network_interface_ids = ["${element(azurerm_network_interface.main.*.id, count.index)}"]
  vm_size               = "Standard_DS1_v2"

  # Uncomment this line to delete the OS disk automatically when deleting the VM
  delete_os_disk_on_termination = true

  # Uncomment this line to delete the data disks automatically when deleting the VM
  # delete_data_disks_on_termination = true

  storage_image_reference {
    publisher = "Canonical"
    offer     = "UbuntuServer"
    sku       = "16.04-LTS"
    version   = "latest"
  }

  storage_os_disk {

    name              = "osdisk"
    caching           = "ReadWrite"
    create_option     = "FromImage"
    managed_disk_type = "Standard_LRS"
  }

  os_profile {
    computer_name  = "${var.hostname[count.index]}"
    admin_username = "testadmin"
    admin_password = "Password1234!"
  }

  os_profile_linux_config {
    disable_password_authentication = false
  }

  tags {
    environment = "staging"
  }
  count = "${length(var.hostname)}"
  depends_on = ["azurerm_network_interface.main"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your construct with setting Count is not producing the expected array of resources but a single resource instead.

You should be able to verify that with a debug log enabled run, by callling `TF_LOG=DEBUG terraform plan`.

Comment: Thanks @marenkay , setting the variable "TF_LOG=DEBUG" was very useful and it lead me to find where the problem was. As I'm using some variables as lists, for example: `region = ["westeurope", "eastasia"]`and attributes were expecting a string the loop was not working: `Errors: [location must be a single value, not a list` I had to use the same construct was in `network_interface_ids = ["${element(azurerm_network_interface.main.*.id, count.index)}"]`to be able to assign those variables.